# Special Characters not correctly being retrieved from Oracle Database

Tags: html, .net, oracle, special-characters

I have an Oracle database that has special characters such as the registered trademark symbol, ®.  In the database all of the special characters show up correctly but when I retrieve them from the database they show up as question marks. For this column in my database I tried using both the types of varchar2 and nvarchar2.

Here is an image of how it looks in the database, it shows correctly

[image]

Here is an image of my call to the database, returns it incorrectly

[image]

How can I get it to return this special character normally so I can display it on the front end?

My application is using .Net 4.5, Entity Framework 5.0, using an Oracle database -PL/SQL 9.0.1

Thanks

Comment: Looks like an issue with the font you're using to display the text fetched from the database. What fonts are being used in each of the above images?

Comment: @BobJarvis Thanks for the reply,  I have not set the font to anything in the database or on the .Net side.  It should be set to whatever the default is.

Comment: It might be good to investigate and find out what fonts are being used. It appears that the font used in your database tool supports the trademark symbol while the font used in whatever tool produced the second image does not. Best of luck.

Comment: I also assume a font issue. Try other characters where you can be sure they are supported by the font, e.g. `ö`

Comment: What is your `NLS_LANG` value (check environment and Registry)? If it is not set then Oracle defaults it to `AMERICAN_AMERICA.US7ASCII` which does not support special characters.

Comment: In order to verify whether it is a problem with your font you can consult this page: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/font/fontlist.htm

Comment: I found the problem to be related with the way the data was encoded. I changed the CSV file that was feeding the oracle table from ANSI to UTF-8 and then it worked for me.  Thanks!